# golang mysql client connection error in concurrent transactions

Tags: mysql, go

I am using the [DB.Begin](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Begin) method. Everything is good in a single threaded environment. However, in a multithreaded environment (let's say 50 threads), some calls return either of the following errors:

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:33306: getsockopt: connection reset by peer

or

> driver: bad connection

The `max_connections` global variable is set to 0 (which is infinite number of concurrent connections).
Is there some other setting I am missing here to avoid these intermittent errors ?

Comment: These errors are probably the result of a connection being closed due to inactivity, not due to exceeding a programmatic limit. The solution should be to make your software handle such errors gracefully (as they're inevitable, just perhaps less common, in any environment--even a single-threaded one)

Comment: It might also be possible to cause such errors by mis-using a single DB handle simultaneously in multiple goroutines (this is purely a guess on my part, I haven't tested). In this case, the solution is just to ensure that you're not using the same db handle in multiple goroutines. Also run your code with the race detector on to help detect this type of problem. Without seeing your code, only guesses are possible.